# Getting total sum of rows and adding and removing rows using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am fairly new to knockoutjs. I am creating a simple table and trying to sum up all the values in the "total" column. Plus, I am also implementing "Add column" and "Remove Column" functionalities using knockoutjs.

The problem is that both the Add and Remove funcitonalities and not working. Plus,the "TotalSurcharge" value is not displaying on the UI.

Here's my js:

```
// Class to represent a row in the table
function addMaterial() {
    this.name = ko.observable("");
    this.quantity = ko.observable("");
    this.rate = ko.observable(0);
    this.formattedTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.rate() * this.quantity();    
    }, this);

}

function documentViewModel(){ 
    var self = this; 

    //create a mateirals array 
    self.materials = ko.observableArray([
        new addMaterial()
    ]);

    // Computed data
    self.totalSurcharge = ko.computed(function() {
       var total = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < self.materials().length; i++)
           total +=  self.materials()[i].formattedTotal();
       return total;
    });  

    // Operations
    self.addMaterial = function() {
        self.materials.push(new addMaterial());
    }
    self.removeMaterial = function(material) { self.materials.remove(material) }

} 


ko.applyBindings(new documentViewModel());
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.2.0.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Quantity </th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody "foreach: materials">
        <tr class="info">
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: quantity" /></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: rate" /></td>        
            <td data-bind="text: formattedTotal"></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeMaterial">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: addMaterial, enable: materials().length < 5">Add Row</button>

<h3 data-bind="visible: totalSurcharge() > 0">
    Total surcharge: $<span data-bind="text: totalSurcharge().toFixed(2)"></span>
</h3>
</div>

</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='application.js'></script>
</html>
```

I checked the console error on the browser but am not getting any error. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot a `new` inside the materials array initialization. Also, your totalSurcharge calculation doesn't make any sense. Shouldn't you be adding each items `formattedTotal` to your sum? `self` doesn't have a `formattedTotal`.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, I got the add and remove to work now. Thanks for ur suggestion. I have modified the totalSurcharge computed function to the best of my knowledge but it's still not working. Any ideas ?

Comment: My bad, forgot the parenthesis after the formattedTotal. Fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you intended to bind the materials to the table body, this is not right:

```
<tbody "foreach: materials">
```

It should be:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: materials">
```

Once that is fixed, everything else appears to work.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p29xnhnh/)